# Why are new users being added to the database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Console application on Node.JS and MongoDB. In one file, I implemented adding users, and in the second, outputting all collection objects to the console. When executing the command - node scripts/get_all_users.js, users are displayed in the console and new ones are added, as when executing a file with adding a user. Although the code for adding users lies in another file. How can this problem be solved?

add_user.js:

```js
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;

const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
const mongoClient = new MongoClient(url);

module.exports = {
  mongoClient
};

let users = [{
    name: "Bob",
  },
  {
    name: "Alice",
  },
  {
    name: "Tom",
  },
];

mongoClient.connect(function(err, client) {
  const db = client.db("expensesdb");
  const collection = db.collection("users");
  collection.insertMany(users, function(err, results) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(results);
    client.close();
  });
});
```

get_all_users.js:

```js
const { mongoClient } = require("./add_users");

mongoClient.connect(function (err, client) {
  const db = client.db("expensesdb");
  const collection = db.collection("users");

  if (err) return console.log(err);

  collection.find().toArray(function (err, results) {
    console.log(results);
    client.close();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
const { mongoClient } = require("./add_users");
```

The code in `add_users` is executed.  That code includes adding users:

```
mongoClient.connect(function(err, client) {
  const db = client.db("expensesdb");
  const collection = db.collection("users");
  collection.insertMany(users, function(err, results) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(results);
    client.close();
  });
});
```

Instead of importing `mongoClient` from `add_users`, just import it plainly the same way you currently do in `add_users`:

```
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;

const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
const mongoClient = new MongoClient(url);
```

Or, to reduce duplication, create a `mongo_client` file which *just creates the client*, but doesn't *add users*:

```
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;

const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
const mongoClient = new MongoClient(url);

module.exports = {
  mongoClient
};
```

And import *that* into both other files:

```
const { mongoClient } = require("./mongo_client");
```